# Rails static page title and color change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have one static page whose title, back-ground color and font can be changed by user and changes should persist with users, it means that if I have two user then if first user changes background color to be yellow and second one changes it to orange then if first user again logged in the application, background color should be yellow for him and if second user logged in it should be orange.

How the change in the color of page can be handled ?

How can I proceed with user table and I used devise for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Create three new columns in your `User` model that will hold their individually set title, background colour and font. You should have preset values already in your CSS files for all these attributes, however if the user does set these values themselves you can access them in your view to modify the CSS by doing something like:

Title example:

```
<div class="title"><%= user.title.nil? ? "Default title" : user.title %></div>
```

Styling example:

```
<div class="blah" style="<%= 'background-color : #{user.backgroundcolor};' unless user.backgroundcolor.nil? %>">
```

Comment: How can I store this value in database?

Comment: They would all be stored in your database. I would do the following: I would make a separate webpage with a form that had three fields. One being the title where the user would enter in whatever title they wanted. The second field should have a select menu for the users to pick their color. And of the third you should just have a select menu for the users to choose their font.

Comment: Have you set up your database for your rails project yet? What are you using MySQL, Postgresql...